# Using method of characteristics to find general solution of PDE $x^3 u_x + y u_x = 4 + 2x^2u$

Tags: partial-differential-equations, characteristics

Use the method of characteristics to find the general solution $u(x; y)$ of the partial differential equation
$$
x^3 \frac{\partial u}{\partial x} + y \frac{\partial u}{\partial x} = 4 + 2 x^2 u
$$

Comment: This in an ODE, not a PDE. Unless you really mean: $$x^3 \frac {\partial u}{\partial x}+y\color {red}{\frac {\partial u}{\partial y}}=4+2x^2 u $$

Answer (score 0):

$$x^3\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}+y\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}=4+2x^2u$$
System of characteristic ODEs :
$$\frac{dx}{x^3}=\frac{dy}{y}=\frac{du}{4+2x^2u}$$
First family of characteristic curves, from $\quad \frac{dx}{x^3}=\frac{dy}{y} \quad\to\quad y\:e^{\left(\frac{1}{2x^2}\right)}=c_1$

Second family of characteristic curves, from $\quad\frac{dx}{x^3}=\frac{du}{4+2x^2u}\quad\to\quad \frac{u}{x^2}+\frac{1}{x^4}=c_2$

General solution of the PDE expressed on the form of implicit equation :
$$\Phi\left(y\:e^{\left(\frac{1}{2x^2}\right)} \:,\: \frac{u}{x^2}+\frac{1}{x^4}\right)=0$$
$\Phi$ is any differentiable function of two variables.

Equivalently, general solution of the PDE expressed on the form of explicit equation : $\quad \frac{u}{x^2}+\frac{1}{x^4}=F\left(y\:e^{\left(\frac{1}{2x^2}\right)} \right)$
$$u(x,y)=-\frac{1}{x^2}+x^2 F\left(y\:e^{\left(\frac{1}{2x^2}\right)} \right)$$
$F$ is any differentiable function.